# How to pass the database data and display it in yii2 highCharts?

Tags: php, highcharts, yii2

I have install the **miloschuman\highcharts\Highcharts**, website : **https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-highcharts-widget**. I have a database with the table columns *lme_price* and *lme_name* which I want to display the price of the copper in the highcharts. I'm using PHP.

Below is my code which I have done. This is the code in my models. I create a static function with the query inside it to find the data that I want from the database.

```
public static function getCopperPrice()
{
    $getCopperPrices = Lme::find()
                    ->select('lme_price')
                    ->where(['lme_name' => 'LME Copper'])
                    ->all();
    return $getCopperPrices;
}
```

Here is my code in the view. I have a table show in the view which show every data from the database.

```
<div class="lme_index">
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //  'searchModel'=> $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'label'=> 'DATE',
            'attribute' => 'lme_title',
        ],
        [
            'label'=> 'MATERIAL',
            'attribute'=> 'lme_name',
        ],   
        [
            'label'=> 'PRICE (US$)',
            'attribute'=> 'lme_price',
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Here is the code for the highcharts graph.

```
<div class = "graph">
    <?= Highcharts::widget([
        'options' => [
            'title' => ['text' => 'Copper Price'],
            'xAxis' => [
                'categories' => []
            ],
            'yAxis' => [
                'title' => ['text' => 'Price $US']
            ],
            'plotOption' => [
            'series' => [
                ['name' => 'Copper', 
                'data' => [lme::getCopperPrices()]],
             ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);?>
```

I want to display only 1 material price in the highcharts. I call the function from the model inside the series but the graph shows nothing on it. The coding there didn't show any error to me.

Can someone help me or tell me how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: `lme::getCopperPrices()` returns `ActiveRecord` object. Try using `Lme::find()->select('lme_price')->where(['lme_name' => 'LME Copper'])->column();`

Comment: @InsaneSkull the output at ther view page there is also same, nothing show in the graph.

Comment: chart or gridview not working? What is the output of `lme::getCopperPrices()`?

Comment: @InsaneSkull My chart not showing anything at first when i change the ->all(); to the one u suggest. The output of the lme::getCopperPrices() shows out the array string but the chart data only accept integer.

I manage to get the data show in the graph by using the foreach loop to loop through the array and convert the string to the integer. Thank you for your helps. 

I really appreciate the opinion you give me. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chart require `integer` values to display

```
public static function getCopperPrice()
{
     $cooperPrices = [];

     $copperPriceList = Lme::find()
         ->select('lme_price')
         ->where(['lme_name' => 'LME Copper'])
         ->column();

    foreach($copperPriceList as $price) {
        $cooperPrices[] = (int) price;
    }

     return $cooperPrices;
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the solution.